# Do I need to create a Storyboard for every Q&A in a quiz/trivia type of iOS applicaiton

Tags: ios, ios7

Please forgive me for my n00bishness.

I am creating an app that asks several questions, and scores the result.  Similar to something like an IQ test.

I would like to not have to create a storyboard for every question.  I was wondering if I could create a storyboard for each question "type" and then populate that storyboard with questions from an array?  For instance, while I may have 100 questions in the app, I want to only give the user 20 each time they run the app and I really only have three question "types":

1. Multiple Choice (one correct answer)
2. Multiple Selection (multiple selections allowed)
3. Yes or No

I would like to be able to create a standard screen for each of these types of questions and then populate the screen with text and scoring parameters from some sort of array.

If that is possible, I would probably like to create a large question set and then only feed in say 20 of 100 possible questions in a random fashion.

It seems like I also should create a "Question" class, and then spawn instances of that class for each question.

Is the the correct way to proceed?

Comment: I think you're using the word "storyboard" incorrectly -- you mean view controllers (or scenes in the storyboard), not storyboards.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create only one view controller for all the questions you are going to display, maintain an array of questions and make IBOutlets and IBActions for all the display components, Maintain current index of the question and write the logic for updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one view controller in storyboard and then you can use different View for each category. Whenever any category is selected you can Hide/Show those corresponding views.

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking is the right approach.

You need to create just one storyboard which you'll be using to display the questions. The questions and the options being displayed on it would be dynamic.

Comment in case you are not able to find a tutorial for the same.

Comment: Found a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJy7fero79U) that appears to lead me down the path a bit, thank you.